# How to recreate youtube full screen videos with scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

Hi I was curious how the fullscreen with scrolling works on a youtube page.

Normally when you put a video in fullscreen there is no scrolling. But for youtube they are able to make the video fullscreen (and by extension the browser) and still allow a user to scroll down the page.

I have a feeling they are doing some sort of trick and "highjacking" the fullscreen function and triggering the video to go into theatre mode.

Not sure where to start at all for the code.

Comment: They probably don't request full screen for the `video` element but for the whole page (e.g. the `body`). Then they just set the height and width of the `video` element to 100% of the viewport height and width.

Comment: Just checked and yes, they request full screen on the `html` element

Comment: @Wendelin mind putting a full answer, and Ill mark this as correct. That way you get the rep!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YouTube just makes the whole `html` element full screen and changes the height and width of the `video` element to 100% of the height and width of the viewport.